# Boggle Jr 8 dice letters

Tags: boggle

My Boggle Jr game set has only 7 dice left (missing one die). Some of the letter cards can't be spelled out using only 7 dice.

I am curious what's missing die should be.

Would someone please post the letters (6 faces) on all 8 dice?

Comment: You would need to provide information about what dice your set currently has for someone to provide an answer. Asking for someone to do a google search and post the images for you probably won't get you an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 8 dice are:

ABCDEF

ABCDEF

ABDEKO

EGRSTZ

GHIJKL

IKLNPW

LMNOPR

OSTUWY

This comes from the file posted [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/14848/bogglejrzip).